# Trying to convert a list of data records to a hashmap

Tags: haskell

Here is the code:

```
import Data.HashMap.Lazy as H

data Connections = Connections { connectionName :: String
                    , cfgProperty  :: !Object
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)

loadConn :: [Connections] -> HashMap k v
loadConn c = H.fromList $ j c
  where j cn = do
              let h = foldl (\l -> [(connectionName l, cfgProperty l)]) cn
              return h
```

OK, I know that "loadConn" is probably not even close.  I've fiddled with some different ideas, but none of them worked out.

Any ideas? Is there more info needed?

Thanks

Comment: Your signature says that I (the caller) get to pick the types for `k` and `v`. I will make my own new types `Foo` and `Bar`, then send a list of `Connections` to `loadConn`. I want a `HashMap Foo Bar` out. Can you do that for me? This should indicate that the type of `loadConn` is *too general*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the do-block is out of place, as you aren't sequencing `IO` actions or writing any other kind of monadic code.

Secondly, if you want the hashmap to have connection names as keys and connection properties as values, the type of your function should reflect that (see also crokeea's comment to the question):

```
loadConn :: [Connections] -> HashMap String Object
```

Thridly, the general idea of building a list that you can give to `H.fromList` is sound, but you want `map` rather than a fold:

```
loadConn :: [Connections] -> HashMap String Object
loadConn cs = H.fromList $ map (\c -> (connectionName c, cfgProperty l)) cs
```

Or, using `.` for function composition and not mentioning the `cs` parameter:

```
loadConn :: [Connections] -> HashMap String Object
loadConn = H.fromList . map (\c -> (connectionName c, cfgProperty c))
```

Note that the function given to `map` converts a *single* connection into a *single* key-value pair. By the way, you'll probably want to change the name of your type from `Connections` to `Connection`, as each of its values appears to amounts to a single connection.